# Android GridView Selector Issue

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-selector

I am using a StaggeredGridView in my application with a custom selector created by me but i must have gotten something terribly wrong with my selector because when i select an item in the gridview, all of the items change their color to green.

Here is the code for gridview item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_selector">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ro.gebs.zonizbeacon.ui.custom.ScaledNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ro.gebs.zonizbeacon.ui.custom.AngledTextView
            android:id="@+id/expired_tv"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_favorite_angle_text"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_favorite_angle_text"
            app:angledText="@string/expired"
            app:backgroundColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            app:angledTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:angledTextSize="@dimen/font_size_plus" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <ro.gebs.zonizbeacon.ui.custom.fonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/store_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_normal"
        android:text="Zara"
        app:fontName="Bold" />

    <ro.gebs.zonizbeacon.ui.custom.fonts.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/offer_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fontName="Regular"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
        android:text="@string/info_about" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green_main_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

This is my adapter class:

```
    public class FavoritesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Offer> {
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public FavoritesAdapter(Context context, List<Offer> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

   /* @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }*/

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_favorite_offer, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ScaledNetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.offerText = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.offer_text);
            holder.storeName = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_name);
            holder.expiredTv = (AngledTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expired_tv);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //holder.offerText.setText("POSITION + "+position);
        final Offer offer = getItem(position);
        Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        if (offer.getActiveUntil() < d.getTime()) {
            holder.expiredTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.expiredTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        ImageUtils.load(holder.imageView, offer.getPngLink(), R.drawable.image_placeholder, R.drawable.image_placeholder);
        holder.offerText.setText(offer.getDescription());
        holder.storeName.setText(offer.getStoreName());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        AngledTextView expiredTv;
        ScaledNetworkImageView imageView;
        CustomFontTextView offerText;
        CustomFontTextView storeName;
    }

}
```

and in my fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);

        gridView = (StaggeredGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.staggeredGridView1);
        //gridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_main_color)));
        gridView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        emptyText = (CustomFontTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.empty_grid_view);

        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.default_padding);
        int itemMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_tell_button);

        gridView.setItemMargin(itemMargin); // set the GridView margin
        gridView.setPadding(margin, margin, margin, 0); // have the margin on the sides as well

        mFavoritesAdapter = new FavoritesAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Offer>());
        mFavoritesAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);

        gridView.setAdapter(mFavoritesAdapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new StaggeredGridView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(StaggeredGridView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Offer o = mFavoritesAdapter.getItem(position);
                if (o != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.BUNDLE_HTML_LINK, o.getHtmlLink());
                    intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.STORE_NAME, o.getStoreName());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                //getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(mOnItemLongClickListener);


        //restartLoader(LOADER_FAVORITES);

        return view;
    }
```

Any ideas as to why it could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your listitems get the state of focussed (while not intended). I always use a selector build like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" >
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/green_bit_transparent"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/green_bit_transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@color/green" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, read too quickly. Can you post your Activity layout (containing the gridview) and adapter code too?

Comment: That exitFadeDuration is a nice touch to the selector.